# Custom C# .Net Standard project template to restrict only c# files

Tags: c#, .net, templates, project, standards

I want to create c# .Net Standard template project and want to restrict the user to add only c# files. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Or .Net framework Console Application will also do but the user should be able to add only c# files.

Comment: what do you mean by only C# files ? Classes are .cs files and you should be able to add classes in your project. So what do you mean by C# files, can you please elaborate it a bit more so that we may help you

Comment: Yes I mean the user should be restricted to add only C# classes and no other kinds.